# Token based and Session based authentication using Ms CRM Web API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there any way to use token based and session based authentication using Web API OData. An instance is on-primes 2016.

If ADFS, then how to add web app and also how to generate api token.

Thanks

Comment: Did you do any research? Have you read carefully: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531009.aspx ?

Comment: yes reach on it and now get it